# How to delete parent node of a dynamically created div via button inside it?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to delete a `<li>` whenever the button inside its div is clicked. The problem is that it does not work for dynamically created `<li>`'s, while it does delete pre-made HTML content but only the first `<li>`.

This is what I've done so far

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <div class="content">
            <div class="b-group>
                <button id="delete"></button>
            </div>
        </div>     
    </li
</ul>
```

Javascript

```
var addButton = document.getElementById('add');
var delButton = document.getElementById('delete');
var list = document.querySelector('ul');

addButton.onclick = function() {
    var newCon = document.createElement('li');

    newCon.innerHTML = 
         '<div class="content">'
        +'<div class="b-group">'
        +'<button id="delete"></button>'
        +'</div>'
        +'</div>';

    listOfRents.appendChild(newCon);
}

delButton.onclick = function() {
    var bye = delete;
bye.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(bye.parentNode.parentNode);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get your parent element using [`event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) and [`Element.closest()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest).

> **Event.target**

Identifies the current target for the event, as the event traverses the DOM. It always refers to the element to which the event handler has been attached, as opposed to `event.target` which identifies the element on which the event occurred.

> **Element.closest()**

The `Element.closest()` method returns the closest ancestor of the current element (or the current element itself) which matches the selectors given in parameter. If there isn't such an ancestor, it returns null.

```js
var addButton = document.getElementById('add'),
  ul = document.querySelector('ul');

addButton.onclick = function() {
  var newCon = document.createElement('li');

  newCon.innerHTML =
    `<div class="content">
       <div class="b-group">
         <button name="del">DEL</button>
        </div>
        </div>`

  ul.appendChild(newCon);
  delButton = newCon.querySelector('[name=del]');
  delButton.onclick = function(e) {
    e.target.closest('li').remove()
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="add">ADD</button>
<ul>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the handler for the element upon creation of the new button, so for every new button that is create a new handler needs to be attached to that button. JavaScript doesn't automatically add click handlers to newly added items, you need to do that yourself. Here is an example:

```js
var addButton = document.getElementById('add');
var delButton = document.getElementById('delete');
var list = document.querySelector('ul');

addButton.onclick = function() {
  var newCon = document.createElement('li');

  newCon.innerHTML =
    '<div class="content">' +
    '<div class="b-group">' +
    '<button id="delete">DEL</button>' +
    '</div>' +
    '</div>';

  list.appendChild(newCon);

  // Get the new button in from the `newCon` element
  let btn = newCon.querySelector('button')
  // Attach an event to that button
  btn.addEventListener('click', e => {
    // Find the closest list item to the button and remove it
    e.currentTarget.closest('li').remove()
  })
}
```

```html
<button id="add">ADD</button>
<ul></ul>
```